# Don't want my WordPress editor to remove <br> and <p> tags

Tags: wordpress, editor

I don't want my WP editor to remove `br` and `p` tags when I'm saving and I don't want to install TinyMCE to achieve it. Just want to use `br` and `p` tags in WP default editor.

Is there a good way?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a necro, but for the `<p>` tag you can add a class or perhaps another property.

e.g.

`<p class="nothing-relevant">Foo</p>`

will not be stripped (using Gutenberg).

Answer (score 0):

there are plugins that are more accurate, but you can just add these lines in `functions.php`

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

See [more info here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

Comment: I think, he don't want to remove br and p tags

Comment: this is what wpautop filter does, so by removing it you lose that feature. See edit

Comment: Thats correct @Khushboo. I want my br and p tags to stay in the editor after saving.

Comment: May be then check for above functions in your function.php file or a plugin for this in your site